# NoClassDefFoundError when using instrumentation on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, javaagents

I am trying to add a javaagent to my bluemix app, this agent uses Instrumentation. The thing is that when I run the application I get the following error:

```
premain() - Instrumentation is already running
...
CWWKF0004E: An unknown exception occurred while installing or removing features. Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: agent.ClassInstrumentorTransform
ERR     at com.ibm.ws.kernel.feature.internal.subsystem.SubsystemFeatureDefinitionImpl.setHeader(SubsystemFeatureDefinitionImpl.java)
ERR     at [internal classes]
```

I have tried creating another agent with the same `Premain-Class` and `Agent-Class` structure but with my own classes and it works, I have tried uploading my own copy of Instrumentation classes and point the javaagent to it using `Class-Path` but the error still appears.

Any sugestion what can be the problem?
I suspect maybe the Bluemix enviorment uses the Instrumentation, any ideas how this might be checked and how I can solve the inter dependency?

Comment: What services do you have bound to your application? Can you try removing any monitoring services (new relic, M&A)?

Comment: Are you able to instrument with a local liberty server?

Comment: Can you show the full exception stack trace from messages.log?  My best guess based on the error message you did provide is you have a class in a feature bundle that is trying to access a class from the javaagent, but you have not added the javaagent package to `org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation` as described in the "Specifying Liberty profile bootstrap properties" knowledge center topic: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_inst_bootstrap.html

Comment: @bkail You are correct, I have added the file and the app starts correctly. Very nice! feel free to add answer so I will accept it.

Comment: @Anton.P Added as an answer.  Glad we were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the error message, it looks like you have a class in a feature bundle that is trying to access a class from the javaagent, but you have not added the javaagent package to `org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation` as described in the [Specifying Liberty profile bootstrap properties](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_inst_bootstrap.html)" topic in the knowledge center topic.